# How to use configurator

Tags: haskell

I read the excellent 24 days of hackage. And i would like to give a try to the package  [configurator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/configurator)

how can i retrieve a list of data like

```
herlist = [1, "foo", true] ?
```

Comment: `[1, "foo", true]` is not a valid Haskell string, as it has no simple type.

Comment: @DonStewart The example is not Haskell code, but a line of a text file to be read using the Configurator library.  It's taken from the Configurator documentation.

Comment: I don't know why this question was closed.  It is an excellent question because this isn't covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have the line

```
herlist = [1, "foo", true]
```

in a configuration file called "example.cfg", then the simplest program to load and show that value would be

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Configurator
import Data.Configurator.Types (Value)

main = do
    cfg <- load [Required "example.cfg"]

    lst <- require cfg "herlist" :: IO Value

    print lst
```

The [`OverloadedStrings`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#overloaded-strings) extension is used so that we can use ordinary string literals as configuration keys without having to explicitly convert them to `Text`.

When looking up the key `"herlist"` we need to explicitly tell the compiler the type we are expecting, because in a simple program like this where we do nothing but print the value, the compiler cannot infer it from context.

The type [`Value`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/configurator/latest/doc/html/Data-Configurator-Types.html#t:Value) is the raw type for configuration values. In a real program we would usually convert the `Value` into a custom type used by our program by defining an instance of the [`Configured`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/configurator/latest/doc/html/Data-Configurator-Types.html#t:Configured) type-class.

Comment: Thx for the helpful answer.  But do i have to pass around "cfg" as a parameter to every function that needs to have access to my config? Or is there any means of being a globally accessible data struct, like being initialized in main and then accessible as say a constant like thing? Still very new to haskell.

Comment: You need to pass it around.